# Quiz code is not working

Tags: java

`enter code here`I am trying top make the code workable but its not working. there is a class, ListOfQuestions but the data does not enter in the list. Its quiz that should have a few questions along with four options with each of them to answer. However Questions do not get into the ListOfQuestions.

will be thankful for your help.

```
 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        ListOfQuestions quiz1 = new ListOfQuestions();
        Quiz quiz = new Quiz(quiz1);
        quiz.add();
        quiz.startQuiz();
    }
}

    import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Question {

    private String question;
    private Map<String, String> choices;
    private String correctAnswer;

    public Question(String question, String correctAnswer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.choices = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
        //System.out.println(question);
    }

    public void addChoices(String option1, String option2, String option3, String option4) {
        this.choices.put("A", option1);
        this.choices.put("B", option2);
        this.choices.put("C", option3);
        this.choices.put("D", option4);
    }

    public String getCorrectAnswer() {
        return this.correctAnswer;
    }
    public String getQuestion() {
        return this.question;
    }

    public void enterChoice(String choice) {
        if (choice.toUpperCase().equals(correctAnswer)) {
            System.out.println("Bingo! your answer is correct");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect answer");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.question;
    }
    /*public void print() {
        Map<Letter, String> question = this.choices.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap :: new));

        question.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k + ": " + v));


    }*/
}
class Quiz{
    private ListOfQuestions quiz;
    public Quiz(ListOfQuestions quiz) {
        this.quiz = quiz;
     }

    public void add() throws ClassCastException{
        try {
            Question question1 = new Question("Question1", "C");
            question1.addChoices("Answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4");
            this.quiz.addQuestion(question1);

            Question question2 = new Question("question2", "B");
            question2.addChoices("answer1", "answer2", "answer3",
                    "answer4");
            this.quiz.addQuestion(question2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }

    public void startQuiz() {
       this.quiz.pickQuestion();
    }

}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListOfQuestions {

    private List<Question> questions;

    public ListOfQuestions() {
        this.questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
    }

    public void addQuestion(Question question) {
        this.questions.add(question);
    }

    public void pickQuestion() {
        for (Question question : this.questions) {
            System.out.println(question);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what the console is printing that indicates the questions are not inserted in the list?

Comment: This `public Quiz(ListOfQuestions quiz) {
        this.quiz = quiz;
     }` looks like a constrcutor but is maybe a method - what is its return type?  Does this code compile?

Comment: The body of class Quiz is missing

Comment: @ScaryWombat I think it is a constructor he just hasn't included the declaration of the Quiz class in the source code. Plus some other missing bits of Quiz

Comment: After filling the blanks in your code and running it, it throws the exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.TreeMap$Entry cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`. If that's what you're getting, why don't you ask about that? If that's not what you're getting, then what is your actual code and output?

Comment: for Quiz class the instance variable is  'private ListOfQuestions quiz;'

Comment: Don't post that in comments. Edit your question, fix the code in the question, and tell us what you expect to happen and what happens instead when running the code. With all the output you get.

Comment: well as for the result i am not able to print the questions, since the questions i want to add to the list dont get added. I am a learner so please take it easy.

Comment: They **are** added. You still haven't posted the output of your program. But this is only the 4th time you're being asked to do that.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.TreeMap$Entry cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
 at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:349)
 at java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:278)
 at Question.toString(Question.java:43)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
 at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
 at ListOfQuestions.pickQuestion(ListOfQuestions.java:18)
 at Quiz.startQuiz(Quiz.java:44)
 at Main.main(Main.java:8)

Comment: well now i changed my toString, and it outputs questions without their 4 options...

Comment: That should be **in the question**. See, so questions **are** being added to the list, since the stack trace shows that the exception is being thrown while trying to print them, by calling their toString() method. Read the answer you got instead of discarding it. It's correct and explains what is wrong. When you have an error, the very first thing you need to do is to read it and understand why it's being thrown, instead of ignoring it anf making wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with `Question.toString()` method. When you iterate over `Map.entrySet()` it returns `Map.Entry (combination of key and value)` not the key from entry.

Example:

```
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> key : this.choices.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(key.getKey() + " : " + key.getValue());
        }
```

Comment: well i have commented that part of code already. write now the list of question is not getting filled with questions and it does not output using toString method.

Answer (score 0):

Here I just changed the code only for the workable,

Add a quiz variable to class Quiz as below,

```
public class Quiz {
ListOfQuestions quiz;
public Quiz(ListOfQuestions quiz) {
    this.quiz = quiz;
 }

public void add() throws ClassCastException{
    try {
        Question question1 = new Question("Question1", "C");
        question1.addChoices("Answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4");
        this.quiz.addQuestion(question1);

        Question question2 = new Question("question2", "B");
        question2.addChoices("answer1", "answer2", "answer3",
                "answer4");
        this.quiz.addQuestion(question2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}

public void startQuiz() {
   this.quiz.pickQuestion();
} 
}
```

Change the toString method in Question class as below,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String sentence = "";
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> key : this.choices.entrySet()) {
        sentence += this.choices.get(key.getKey());
    }
    return this.question;
}
```

This code changes are only for the workable of your code.

Comment: Thank you, now it works. now I have to make one small change that is to add the key along with answer choices, and will figure out how by myself. thanks again :)

Comment: Pleasure to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `toString()` method contains a `suspicious call`, and can simply be modified just to return:

```
return this.question + " " + this.getCorrectAnswer();
```